PyInstaller no longer works; "AttributeError: Failed to retrieve attribute __file__ from module pythoncom"
My copy of PyInstaller (executed with my Spyder editor) worked fine for months, and then one day I turned my computer off and on again, and the program which had worked one hour before no longer worked at all.
(My Spyder also no longer recognized modules like EasyGui and Selenium, but I found a way around that by adding the folders/directories that contained those module files to Spyder's PYTHONPATH manager.)
import PyInstaller.__main__
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk
root1 = Tk()
root1.title("File Importer")       
root1.filenames = filedialog.askopenfilename\
(initialdir = "\\", title = "Select file to be imported.",
filetypes = [("all files","*.*")])
root1.destroy() 
print(root1.filenames)
file = root1.filenames
root1 = Tk()
folder = filedialog.askdirectory() 
root1.destroy()
print (folder)
PyInstaller.__main__.run([
   '--onefile',
   f'--distpath={folder}',
   f'{file}',
])

When I try to execute PyInstaller, this is the end of the second error message:

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\stdhooks\hook-pythoncom.py:21
    dll_filename = get_pywin32_module_file_attribute('pythoncom')

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py:376 in get_pywin32_module_file_attribute
    return get_module_attribute(module_name, '__file__')

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py:292 in get_module_attribute
    raise AttributeError(f"Failed to retrieve attribute {attr_name} from module {module_name}") from e

AttributeError: Failed to retrieve attribute __file__ from module pythoncom


(There was a first half / error message, but the Spyder IPython Console pane won't display the first part of the error message anymore. It gets crowded out before I can even take a screenshot.)
I've looked into similar problems posted here, but none of the solutions work.
I've tried turning the computer off and on again, as well as constantly resetting my Spyder editor's kernel after every attempted solution.
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling pywin32 and pypiwin32.
I've tried copy-and-pasting pythoncom39.dll and pywintypes39.dll into every folder that had  pythoncom38.dll and pywintypes38.dll , as well as the folders with  python39.dll. To basically any folder with a name like "win32".
I've tried installing "pywin32_postinstall.py", and I've tried reinstalling and updating PyInstaller. Though I don't know if I did either thing right.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please just include the full traceback error as well as the relevant parts of your code.

Do you know how to force IPython Console to not erase previous outputs? Because the error report seems so long that the first part is unavailable, and it disappears too fast to screenshot.

I have edited the post to add the code I am using to run PyInstaller

[SO]: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Check [SO]: How do I ask a good question? or
[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))
for more asking related details.
Also, [JonSkeet.CodeBlog]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION might be a good point to start. Your environment seems quite complex. Reproduce the problem outside Spyder (and other related junk).
